# How to use PlaceHolder in CKEditor by using asp.net?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ckeditor

This is my code

config.js:-

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config )
{
config.ToolbarLocation = 'None';
config.extraPlugins = 'newplugin';
config.contentsCss = '../ckeditor/mysitestyles.css';
config.toolbar = 'MyToolbar';
config.toolbar_MyToolbar =
    [
        ['Bold', '-', 'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight',   '-', 'Link', 'Unlink', 'CreatePlaceholder'],
        ['Newplugin']
    ]
};
```

I placed CreatePlaceholder in tollbar options but that option will not be rendered on CKEditor.

This is my Default.aspx:-

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <CKEditor:CKEditorControl ID="editor" CustomConfig="/ckeditor/config.js" runat="server" Height="500" EnableTheming="true">
    </CKEditor:CKEditorControl> </form>
  </body>
```

In the above code i want to show placeholder on ckeditor.

Comment: Any error received ? Check in the browser console using inspect element.

Comment: No error will be occured